# How do I get all uploaded video from my user account in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have scenario that I would like to have all video, uploded from my user account in TableView  . I don't want other video. I know about to get the video using searching keyword. But I want it which are uploaded through my account only.

I passed through many things and search on it but can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag variable which is set to true when video is uploaded from your account. And when you request for list of video pass the parameter to send list of only uploaded videos.

Answer (score 0):

When I read your question I wonder 3 things:

1. What type of account are you referring to?
2. To where is the video uploaded, and how?
3. Do I make a correct guess if I assume that you are developing an application from where users can log in and upload videos to some kind of service?

Assuming the answer to 3 is YES, then here is a suggested answer to your question:

Create an SQLite Database in your app with a table called "Videos" or such. Let that table have columns for video ID, name, length, date uploaded and any other information that can be useful in your app. Whenever the user uploads a video from your app, insert a new row in your SQlite table with information about that video.

This table should contain the information that you need to show in the TableView of your app.  When the user clicks a video or if you need to do other things like showing a thumbnail, load the video from the iPhone using ID or name stored in the table.